# Ссылка, размещенная внутри метода(Java)

Tags: java

Такая ситуация: существует условный метод play(), в котором помимо основного кода создаётся объект с помощью ссылочной переменной. Вопрос заключается в следующем: что случается с ссылкой и объектом, когда метод покидает стек(заканчивает работу)?
Смущает меня то, что все локальные переменные теряются при выполнении метода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После завершения работы метода кадр стека уничтожается вместе со всеми локальными переменными, которые в нём хранятся. Если ссылка на созданный в методе объект сохранялась только в локальную переменную, то он становится недоступен и при следующем запуске сборщика мусора будет уничтожен.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Сергей!